# What if I delete a class instance in Blazor?

Tags: c#, blazor

Scenario:

1. I create a new class instance (in my case a Player for a game, including their points this session, their chosen avatar graphic, etc.)
2. I add a reference to a Singleton service (the game server)
3. The player leaves

Question:

**Would that reference be maintained by Blazor, since it is still active somewhere (the server), or would the creating object, if disposed, take down the reference, leading to a null error in the server?**

I've tried just doing it, but the page seems to be maintained even after the user leaves.  I'm worried that an untimely garbage collection could lead to null exceptions, but I'm curious if Blazor (C#?) is smart enough not to dispose references that have been passed to other objects.

Comment: Is the class instance just a class or a service?  If it's just a class then it remains active while it is referenced.  As soon as the last reference is destroyed, it's up for garbage collection.  in your instance, as long as the singleton service holds a reference, then it remains active.

Comment: Yes, it's just an instantiated class, not a service.  Thanks, that's very good to know.

Comment: Shaun can you make this an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the class instance just a class or a service? If it's just a class then it remains active while it is referenced. As soon as the last reference is destroyed, it's up for garbage collection. In your instance, as long as the singleton service holds a reference, then it remains active.